# Python Matplotlib same bar width in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a figure with 6 bar subplots where the bars should all have the same width (the smallest width as in the subplot in the top right corner (ax2 which has 7 bars)). Based on previous posts, I tried to define a uniform bar width for all subplots, but when the plot is created, the bars still have different widths. Can someone please help me to fix this? Many thanks!

```
#Bar charts of % consuming quorn in different social groups
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(5, 6.3))

#Income
x1=['IQ1', 'IQ2', 'IQ3', 'IQ4', 'IQ5']
h1 = [10, 11, 16, 17, 22]
w=0.4
ax1.bar(x1, h1, width=w)
ax1.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax1.set_title('Income')


#Age
x2=['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70+'] 
h2 = [16, 25, 29, 28, 22, 12, 7] 
ax2.bar(x2, h2, width=w)
ax2.set_title('Age')


#Gender
x3=['Male', 'Female'] 
h3 = [12, 20] 
ax3.bar(x3, h3, width=w)
ax3.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax3.set_title('Gender')


#Education
x4=['No HE', 'HE'] 
h4 = [13, 25] 
ax4.bar(x4, h4, width=w)
ax4.set_title('Education')


#Health status
x5=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] 
h5 = [6, 8, 10, 12, 14] 
ax5.bar(x5, h5, width=w)
ax5.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax5.set_title('Health status')


#Diet
x6=['Not veg.', 'Veg.'] 
h6 = [15, 35] 
ax6.bar(x6, h6, width=w)
ax6.set_title('Diet')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTB30.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in barplots. But they are in fact the same width since you have specified it so. The problem is that different amount of columns etc are changing the focus. Playing around and setting some limit for x might help:

```
ax1.set_xlim(-1,len(x1))
ax2.set_xlim(-1,len(x1))
```

Gave this result:
[two first plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttLKc.png)

It is not ideal, I know. However, it is a start. Hope this helps a bit :)

EDIT:
I obviousely pasted in the lines where they belong:

```
ax1.set_xlim(-1,len(x1))
ax1.bar(x1, h1, width=w)
ax1.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax1.set_title('Income')
```

Comment: Many thanks Sabsa! I think this could work if I use xlim of the plot with the most bars (ax2), and then perhaps I can define the position of the bars so that they are centred in each subplot?